# Intent Extract Data Dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Currently I want to know if it is possible to extract data dynamically for intent. I understand we can extract values and categories like so:

```
String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("barcode");
```

However, the application I am building can pass in different intents. The first instance could be:

> barcode="1234" applicationNo="XYZXX"

The second instance could be:

> reg="BG12 YOA" color="blue"

Is there way to dynamically extract information? I have tried the following but have had no luck:

```
TreeMap<String, String> data = new TreeMap<String, String>();
System.out.println("we hit herefas " + this.getIntent());
Object[] catagories = this.getIntent().getCategories().toArray();
for(Object catagory: catagories) {
   data.put(catagory.toString(), this.getIntent().getStringExtra(catagory.toString()));
}
```

EDIT: data is passed in from javascript to the android app. It runs the following command (as an example):

```
./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://print.xxx.cloud?barcode=ABCDEFG"
```

Comment: are you want to use it in deep link ?

Comment: Please use format like url and seperate it with Question mark(?) and parse it at receiver side.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()

Comment: If I understood you right, then you could create an `Serializable` object with all fields(but you will set only those you get/want) and pass it between intents.

Comment: @CommonsWare data has not previously been added using putExtra(), so it would not work, unless I am missing something?

Comment: "data has not previously been added using putExtra()" -- how *are* you putting the data into the `Intent`? You indicate that you already have code for this ("the application i am building can pass in different intents"), so provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are constructing those `Intent` objects.

Comment: @CommonsWare see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be creating `ACTION_VIEW` `Intents` with a `Uri` like `https://print.xxx.cloud?barcode=ABCDEFG`. If so, call `getData()` on the `Intent` to get the `Uri`, and call methods [like `getQueryParameterNames()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameterNames()) to get the names of the query parameters on that `Uri`.

Comment: Ahh i can stop bashing my head against the wall now. Many thanks :D